# Laravel Validation Rule 'same' Negation Check

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to write a simple validation rule in laravel framework.

```
$rules = array(
    'from_account' => 'required',
    'to_account'   => 'required|same:from_account',
    'amount'       => 'required|numeric',
    'description'  => 'required'
);
```

Now as you can see the validation rule `same:from_account` will check and must require to be `to_account` exactly same as `from_account` I am looking to validate for exactly opposite, so that, `to_account` can't be same as `from_account`.

Is there any way to tell this negation check inside the rule or do I have to check it manually?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why not check the docs [here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-different).

And use this:

```
'to_account'   => 'required|different:from_account',
```

or even (for funzies):

```
'from_account' => 'required|different:to_account',
'to_account'   => 'required|different:from_account',
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I missed this rule from the list. Thanks.

Comment: @Rana sure, happens all the time. :)

Comment: @majidarif, good job. Can this takes multiple compared fields or just one?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`different`](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-different) rule:

```
$rules = array(
    'from_account'  => 'required',
    'to_account'    => 'required|different:from_account',
);
```